# How to chain where conditions with OR operator?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I need to retrieve all the `posts` which contains the following conditions as default: `language, type, status`.

Since this is a search system I need to check if the title or the content contains a specific search term, so I did:

```
 $posts = Post::where([
            ['language', '=', $locale],
            ['type', '=', 'post'],
            ['status', '=', 'publish'],
            ['title', 'LIKE', "%$s%"]
        ])
            ->orWhere('content', 'like', "%$s%")
            ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
            ->paginate(5);
```

now the problem is the following:

if the title contains the searched term, all the post with `language, type and status` are correctly returned. But the `orWhere` will return only the posts which match as content the searched term.

Is there a way to replicate `language, type and status` condition also in the `orWhere` clause without rewrite each time this: (?)

```
['language', '=', $locale],
['type', '=', 'post'],
['status', '=', 'publish'],
```

After a bit of playground the correct syntax is:

```
 $posts = Post::where([
            ['language', '=', $locale],
            ['type', '=', 'post'],
            ['status', '=', 'publish'],
        ])->where(function ($query) use ($s) {
            $query->where('title', 'LIKE', "%$s%")
                ->orWhere('content', 'LIKE', "%$s%");
        })
            ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
            ->paginate(5);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should group the searchterm fields in an orWhere which is part of the "and"Where. Sth. like this regarding the docs https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#or-where-clauses

```
$posts = Post::where([
        ['language', '=', $locale],
        ['type', '=', 'post'],
        ['status', '=', 'publish'],
        function($query) {
            $query->orWhere([
                ['title', 'LIKE', "%$s%"],
                ['content', 'LIKE', "%$s%"]
            )
        }
    ])
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know this! But is possible paginate and order too? Also when I use `paginate` or `get` I get this error: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '3' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `posts` where (`language` = en and `type` = post and `status` = publish and `3` = (select * where (`title` LIKE %% and `content` LIKE %%))) and `posts`.`deleted_at` is null order by `date` desc)`

Comment: any help on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Hope it will work.

```
  $post = Post::where(function ($query) use ($s) {
    return $query->where(
      ['language', '=', $locale],
      ['type', '=', 'post'],
      ['status', '=', 'publish']
    )->orWhere(
        ['title', 'LIKE', "%$s%"],
        ['content', 'LIKE', "%$s%"]
    )
  })->orderBy('date', 'desc')->paginate(5);
```